How to setup Cassandra 3-node cluster in Virtual Machine
I'm trying to setup the 3 node Cassandra cluster on virtual machine(Laptop).
Have created 3 VMs and installed Cassandra. While configuring the cassandra.yaml
with listen address with Node IP Cassandra restarting automatically but status was not started.
Kindly advise how to configure the cassandra.yaml below parameters for 3 node Cassandra cluster.
if even after used node IP address cluster unable to come up.

Listen_address
rpc_address
broadcast_address
broadcast_rpc_address

Please suggest.
Cassandra Version:
Cassandra 5.0.2
Linux
firewall enabled for 9042 & 7000 & 7001
max_map_count increased to 1048575
Have commented JVM_OPTS hostname in Cassandra-env.sh  with Node IP still same result.
Couple of times started Cassandra services and VM as well.
Still same result.
Please help me where in the configuration missing.
